# Html elements are left aligned after conversion from html to pdf using jspdf

Tags: javascript, html

```
const pdfDownload = e => {
   let doc = new jsPDF("p", 'px', 'A2');
   doc.html(document.getElementById('pdf-view'), {
      callback: () => {
        doc.save('test.pdf');
      }
   });
}
```

I am using this code to convert to pdf using jspdf

Comment: Can you maybe give us the html code as well, which should be converted to HTML.

Comment: It is centered in every screen but okay I WILL